# Capturar informação de Json usando Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

Estou trabalhando com a API SWAPI com Python e encontro a seguinte dificuldade: Quando obtenho as informações de um Json, é retornado dict quando acesso a key search, obtenho uma list, porém não consigo pegar o 'name' contido nela.

```
import requests
import sys
import json

nome = 'Tatooine'
url = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/'
resp = requests.get(url, params={'search': nome})

if resp.status_code != 200:
    # This means something went wrong.
    raise resp.__getstate__('GET /planets/1 {}'.format(resp.status_code))


planeta = resp.json()
print(type(planeta))
print(planeta.keys())
print(type(planeta['results']))

x = planeta['results'][0]

print(x)
```

Aqui está o que é obtido com o código

```
<class 'dict'>
dict_keys(['count', 'next', 'previous', 'results'])
<class 'list'>
{'name': 'Tatooine', 'rotation_period': '23', 'orbital_period': '304', 'diameter': '10465', 'climate': 'arid', 'gravity': '1 standard', 'terrain': 'desert', 'surface_water': '1', 'population': '200000', 'residents': ['https://swapi.co/api/people/1/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/2/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/4/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/6/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/7/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/8/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/9/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/11/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/43/', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/62/'], 'films': ['https://swapi.co/api/films/5/', 'https://swapi.co/api/films/4/', 'https://swapi.co/api/films/6/', 'https://swapi.co/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.co/api/films/1/'], 'created': '2014-12-09T13:50:49.641000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-21T20:48:04.175778Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/'}
PS C:\Users\thiag\OneDrive\Documentos\Desenvolvimento\star_wars\__init__.py\src>
```

Preciso que o código retorne apenas a value Tatooine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perceba que o tipo de dado de `planeta['results'][0]` é um dicionário. Isto quer dizer, que eu posso então buscar pela chave ['name'] (Que é a que está guardando o valor *Tatooine*).

```py
x = planeta['results'][0]['name']
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acabei encontrando mais uma possível solução:

```
planeta = resp.json()
valor = planeta['results'][0]
print(planeta.keys())
print(f'Repository name: {valor["name"]}')
```